# Sharepoint 2010 What's new?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I wonder that, with a use of minimum custom code use, how easy or hard would it be, compared to previous versions, to build a community portal in Sharepoint 2010, in which users upload, view and comment videos, share videos and so on.

You can ofcourse take Youtube as an example.

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to run YouTube on SharePoint? I mean apart from 'because you can' what are the business reasons for doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this Walkthrough:

Walkthroughs: Creating and Customizing a Video Sharing Site

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff464364.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Some links from Microsoft.com:

- [What's New in Microsoft SharePoint
  Server 2010](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee518662.aspx)
- [What's New in SharePoint Server 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee557323.aspx)
- [Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Overview](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/product/capabilities/Pages/default.aspx)